# Zoom Conference (skype type of program) not working

Tags: zoom-meeting

Just recently Zoom conference is offering to install their program on Ubuntu, but I am not able to make it work.

I went here to download the .deb file from https://zoom.us/download to install it via the software center.

The installation goes really fast, probably too fast and then when starting the program, the first page shows up where I have "join meeting" or "log in" options available but none of both options works. The program freezes and I can not close the window.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: OK, I figured out some of it with the current answer but I am getting these error messages: E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0'

Comment: I am trying to download the  64 bit version.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

Installation

```
dpkg -i ZoomInstaller_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Should you come across any issues or be using the tar file to install, the following is the list of commands to install required dependencies

Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

```
sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa
```

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

> sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386 libegl1-mesa:i386 libxcb-shape0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libxi6:i386 libsm6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libxrender1:i386 libpulse0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386

Source: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Getting-Started-on-Linux

Comment: yes, I read all that, I amon ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS so no extra installation. I did try the terminal install instead of the software center: same results.... try it out yourself and see if you can make it work,  it works much faster then skype and you can do multiple video group calls...

Comment: @michael on 14.04.2 you have some dependencies to meet, at least that is what I understand from the instructions I copied for you here, so uninstall it first, then run the command to install required dependencies and then finally install your app again.  Also check my update in installation instructions, I added `sudo apt-get -f install` from the documentation, it is weird but I think they had a reason.

Comment: ok, I uninstalled then I did the commands and it says 0 to isntall....

Comment: @michael so I tried to install it on 12.04 today, sorry but I don't have 14.04 and it did work, but I had to run the `sudo apt-get -f install` after install, at first it then do the install again, because first time I hade some errors.

Comment: hmmmm... i do: sudo apt-get remove zoom

Comment: and then sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: and it is still not working

Comment: what is strange is that the installation takes only 20seconds to be done....

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use GDebi tool to install the Zoom .deb file (and any other "offline" .deb files). It automatically downloads and installs all dependencies.

Install GDebi with `sudo apt-get install gdebi`, then launch GDebi from the graphical menu and open the .deb file.